# Remote execution of commands using the Django ORM

Tags: python, django, orm

Can I somehow work with remote databases (if they can do it) with the Django ORM?

It is understood that the sitting has spelled out the local database. And periodically to make connection to various external databases and perform any sort of commands such as load dump.

Answer (score 1):

If you can connect to the database remotely, then you can simply specify its host/port in `settings.py` exactly as you would a local one.